Issue with Margin During Navigation Transition in iOS 18
The new .navigationTransition feature introduced in SwiftUI for iOS 18+ offers an impressive animated screen transition. However, during the transition, the parent view shrinks, leaving a white margin (or black in dark mode) around the edges.

If the background color of the parent view matches this margin color, it appears seamless. However, as shown in the attached example, when using a custom color or gradient background, the margin becomes visually disruptive.
Is there a way to address this?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                NavigationLink {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
                        Text("Detail View")
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Transition")
                    .navigationTransition(.zoom(sourceID: "hellow", in: namespace))
                } label: {
                    Text("Open")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .matchedTransitionSource(id: "hellow", in: namespace)
                }

            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .background(Color.mint.ignoresSafeArea())
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Applying .ignoreSafeArea() to the background view doesn’t seem to resolve the issue, which suggests this margin might not be related to the safe area. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

The space at the edges is being caused by a scaling effect being applied to the background. The background is being made smaller, so it no longer fills the frame.
As a workaround, I would suggest adding some negative padding to the background. This way, the background starts off larger than the frame it is filling and remains larger than the frame, even after being scaled down.
On an iPhone 16, increasing the size by -50 on all sides seems to do the trick:
Form {
    // ...
}
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.background {
    Color.mint
        .padding(-50)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}



Wow, what an amazing solution!
Thank you so much; I never would have thought of using a negative padding value. I’ll adjust it slightly with a bit of extra negative space to account for possible changes in future devices’ safe area sizes. With this, I can create a beautiful UI!

@KngwKngw Yes, adding a bit of reserve is probably a good idea. If you are using a solid color then you can make the reserve quite big, but if you are using a gradient or an image then you probably won't want to exceed what is needed by too much. I think the threshold amount on an iPhone 16 is actually about 40. Ps. Thanks for accepting the answer!
